# tizen on gear s3 get/set information to app on connected phone

Tags: widget, alarm, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am developing a widget/app for the gear s3 smartwatch. In particular, I would like to build something similar to the Alarm widget that comes pre-installed on the gear.

What I can't find is any information about is connecting to the phone and getting alarm info. There are android java api's for doing this (on a phone device), but, again, I can't find anything for a native tizen app on the gear s3.

Any info, pointers, etc. greatly appreciated.

TIA

ken

(PS: I do know that the tizen IDE comes with a sample alarm widget, but it is only a GUI, no functional code. That's what I need.)

Sorry guys. I guess I wasn't clear enough: 1) I have built the "alarm widget" sample- it is mostly the GUI part (see #2); 2) the "alarms" that you have pointed out are really just "timed callbacks". They have nothing to do with the alarms available on the phone's clock app.

I did find something about "com.android.alarmclock" on github ([here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock/blob/master/src/com/android/alarmclock/Alarm.java)). How does one get access to something like that via tizen c?

Answer (score 0):

See this link on how to develop Tizen Wearable Native Widget Application.
https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/native-application/getting-started/creating-your-first-tizen-wearable-native-widget-application

Alarm Sample Overview with code hint
https://developer.tizen.org/development/sample/native/AppFW/Alarm

API: The Alarm API allows setting an "alarm clock" for the delivery of a notification at some point in the future. 
https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__ALARM__MODULE.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this on github (https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock/tree/master/src/com/android/alarmclock) This is pretty much what I need. Now I just have to translate from android/java to tizen/c. For the latter this (https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory) will also be useful, although it might not look so.

Just to clarify and maybe help with the next poster: I really should have been more careful when using the word "alarm". I know about the alarm api's in tizen, but as mentioned these are specific to one app instance. I really wanted to communicate with an app running on the connected phone - ie, the alarmclock app.